# Nginx: Return 301 Redirect When 404 Error

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, nginx

What I want to do whenever I get a 404 error on my domain, automatically 301 to the homepage.

I have a lot of old blog posts and such that were linked to, but I don't have them on the blog and if anyone happens to click through from another site that they get kicked to the homepage.

How can I do this inside nginx?

```
 server {
        listen             12680;
        root       /home/noahc/webapps/nginx/html/noahc/;
        server_name    www.noahc.net, noahc.net;
        error_page 404 @foobar;

        location @foobar {
                rewrite  .*  / permanent;
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the final solution that I got to work using webfaction.

```
server {
        listen             12440;
        root       /some/path/here/nginx/html/noahc/;
        server_name    www.domain.net, domain.net;
        port_in_redirect off;

        location /{
            error_page 404 =  @foobar;
        }

        location @foobar {
            rewrite  .*  / permanent;
        }    
 }
```

Answer (score 23):

There's a faster way through it:

```
error_page 404 = @foobar;

location @foobar {
  return 301 /;
}
```

By "faster" I mean "no useless regexp matching inside web server" by using [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) instead of rewrite.

Comment: Brilliant I like it

Answer (score 14):

This should work:

```
error_page 404 = @foobar;

location @foobar {
    rewrite  .*  / permanent;
}
```

Comment: I have this setup on noahc.net. Whenever I type something in http://noahc.net/not-real-page.html for example, I get sent to a mediacom dns error page. Any ideas? I've restarted nginx.

Comment: I get `404 Not Found nginx/1.0.6` when visiting the above (non existing link), maybe it's a problem on your side (client-side)?

Comment: in any case doesn't that mean it's not quite working right? Shouldn't I be getting the redirect part and the 301 error or no?

Comment: Yes, it's not working right, you should get redirected. Please post your `server {..}` block, maybe something else is preventing it from working.

Comment: It seems that isn't the right server{}-block, since your website is running on port 80 and not on 12680  (`listen  12680;`). Otherwise the block looks ok and should work.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, but I'm using webfaction and essentially what nginx does is sit on port 80 and redirects to the port that is listening. Could this cause it not to work?

Comment: Don't know about webfaction, but it seems that causes the problem, since the configuration you showed works with nginx alone (`listen 80;`)

Comment: I'll hit up support and see if they can help. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine, just missing an equals sign: `error_page 404 = @foobar;`

Answer (score 10):

The `error_page` setting can do this for you already:

`error_page 404 =301 http://example.com/;`