# nginx showing blank page for invalid url

Tags: ember.js, nginx

I have an emberjs app and using nginx to serve it. I want to redirect to index page if the file not found. I tried using the following configuration but its showing blank page instead of index page.

```
server
{
  listen 80 ;
  server_name x.x.x.x
              xyz.example.com;

  root /home/ubuntu/website/dist/;
  index index.html index.htm;
  error_page 404 /home/ubuntu/website/dist/;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /fallback/index.html;
  }

location /fallback {
    root /home/ubuntu/website/dist;
}
}
```

I added the following block after the reference

```
location /{
        error_page 404 =  @foobar;
}

location @foobar {
    rewrite  .*  / permanent;
}
```

Finally, the conf file look like this

```
server
{
  listen 80 ;
  server_name X.X.X.X
              xyz.example.com;

  root /home/ubuntu/website/dist/;
  index index.html index.htm;

error_page 404 = @foobar;
location /{
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}

        location @foobar {
            rewrite  .*  / permanent;
        }
}
```

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147862/nginx-return-301-redirect-when-404-error

Comment: @AntonF Thnx for the reference. I did search a lot but couldn't find the right reference.

Comment: @AntonF That post was somehow useful but that causes an issue. It always redirect to index page even if we enter a valid url.

Comment: Update OP with your last changes.

Comment: @AntonF see the update in question

Answer (score 0):

After update of OP

```
location /{
        error_page 404 =  @foobar;
}
```

Should be

```
location /{
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @foobar;
}
```

Comment: This is also alway redirecting to index page even if I enter valid url like xyz.example.com/login

Comment: No difference. Always redirecting to index page whether it is a valid or invalid url.